# Java NIO2 AIO - TCP Chat Server

Tags: java, nio2

i am playing arround with Java NIO2 and i am trying to code a TCP Chat Server based on AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.

To Programm a simple ECHO-Server was no problem and worked flawlessly. Now i am trying to accept many clients and to broadcast incomming messages to all connected clients, but i am facing problems.

Because it got a bit long i posted the code [here in pastbin](http://pastebin.com/7hxyj2z5)

Until now i am able to broacast one message, after that something goes wrong and after awhile i get the following error:

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-13" java.nio.channels.WritePendingException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-13" java.nio.channels.WritePendingException

This means you attempted to write with out waiting for the previous write to complete.  When you call write() with NIO2 you get a Future which you can wait on to check that it has finished.

I wouldn't recommend using NIO2 unless you have infiniband (which is what it was designed for) NIO2 is at least twice as complicated as NIO to use and I wouldn't even suggest using NIO unless you are using simple blocking NIO or a library like netty or mina.

For a chat program I would just use plain NIO or even IO. Or you could re-use one of the [many, many  chat libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/chat-servers) which already exist and work. ;)

Comment: But whats about performance? Isnt aio faster than nio or even blocking io? I did recently program a high scalable websocket server in c and libevent and was able to achieve 300K connections. Can i achieve the same with blocking io in java? I think i really need AIO to achieve an equivalent performance.

Comment: Do you need to save a few micro-seconds latency?  From my tests NIO2 is slower as it creates garbage and passes tasks to background threads.  Perhaps future versions will be faster but for now you really need Infiniband I suspect. Do you need 300K active connections per server? Do you have that many active/concurrent users but cannot afford to buy a second machine? If so I suggest using an established NIO library be willing to buy a realistic amount of hardware.

Comment: "I think i really need AIO to achieve an equivalent performance" I would be interested to see the business case for that I suspect you need to rethink what your assumptions are.  Note: you will have much more passing of data between threads and GCs with async NIO2.

Comment: This answer in no way explains how to fix the error provided, or even hints at a solution.

Comment: @Christian.tucker You must be reading a different answer to me. It doesn't hint at a solution; it says what the problem is and what the solution is.